# Show stacked bar chart in Application

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin.android, bar-chart

How can I show chart shown in below image in my App? It is shown in Settings->Apps->Running. I tried Microcharts but it isn't possible using it. I want to show it for storage space. I know how to get the storage space values but don't know how to plot chart like in the image.

[image: Memory Chart]

Answer (score 0):

You mean a stacked bar diagram. It is possible with NumAndroidCharts Library, in this example they make a horizontal one. Maybe you are able to use it vertical as well:

https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-stacked-bar-chart-using-numandroidcharts-tutorial/

But i don't now if you can hide the X and Y coord description, so it would look like in your picture. Maybe it is easier for you to draw it on your own, the diagram are simple rectangles.

---

**Update**

Found the horinzontal one:
https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-horizontal-stacked-bar-using-numandroidcharts-tutotrial/

Comment: I found this library before but I am looking for the inbuilt solution if possible. Found this type of graph in many places in Settings. It will be great if I can reproduce the same thing in my App.

Comment: There is no such inbuilt solution in Android. So the only other way would be draw it on your own, than you can design it to look like the android diagram.